# hibernate change data structure

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

i am new in hibernate. i just learn it from [hibernate tuto](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html).
i am glad that i don't have to type manualy the class for CRUD operation.
(i am from .NET side). i think it is like Entity Framework on .NET side.

but then i think, what happen when i change the structure, or data type on my database ?
when i forgot another table after generation, how can i regenerate it again ?

on .NET world, i just have to delete the table and put it again after modification and regenerating the solution.

how can i do that on J2EE world ?

Comment: If I understood your question, you want to know what you need to do when you want to change the structure of your DB. You just need to update the entities and the queries (if you have more specific queries than the CRUD ones). If you are using the auto generation you just need to change the Entities I think and in the startup of your program the hibernate will generate your DB.

Comment: Want to generate schema? Out of the box? `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It is ORM therefore mostly the same as entity framework.
If you want to generate or change your database structure from your entities you can do it this way:

In your persistence.xml or hibernate.properties add line hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

you can use one of these values:

- **create-only**

  *Database creation will be generated.*
- **drop**

  *Database dropping will be generated.*
- **create**

  *Database dropping will be generated followed by database creation.*
- **create-drop**

  *Drop the schema and recreate it on SessionFactory startup. Additionally, drop the schema on SessionFactory shutdown.*
- **validate**

  *Validate the database schema*
- **update**

  *Update the database schema*

You can read more about setup [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)

**Use this way to change your schema in productive environment is strongly not recommended (However, you can let Hibernate to generate the changes into the script)**